# Can not connect to my sql database

Tags: amazon-ec2, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to mysql database on amazon through a php script, but I am shown this error:

> **Warning:** mysql_connect()
>   [function.mysql-connect]: Lost
>   connection to MySQL server at 'reading
>   initial communication packet', system
>   error: 111

I have tried and searched places and did the following things:

- In "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" I commented out the line `bind address: 127.0.0.1` to allow the acccess to all.
- checked /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny and made sure that there are no rules present that may cause

But still no luck. Please suggest any other way.

Thanks,
Madhup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you connect from php to 127.0.0.1 ?

are you sure you have restarted your mysql after changing the configuration file?

can you connect to mysql using command line:

```
mysql -uroot -psomePass -h127.0.0.1
```

do you see on what port mysql listens? can it be it is non-standard port?

```
netstat -lanp|grep mysqld|grep LISTEN
```

is it possible that your iptables does not allow connections over loopback? run

```
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I have got it working right now. The problem was that mysql was not getting restarted. It failed to restart but today it restarted, any suggestion or idea why it was not restarting or it happens sometimes without any reason.

Comment: @madhup corrupted/removed by mistake pidfile comes to my mind as possible excuse for that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [MySQL forum post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,152265,244182) that should help.

Answer (score 1):

how is binding mysql to 127.0.0.1 allowing access to all? if you're connecting from an external server, you'll need to bind mysql to the external IP address, so that you can connect remotely.

you may also wish to add some firewall rules, i.e.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s <php_host_ip> -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

to block access to mysql from any other hosts, even though mysql is supposed to take care of itself, it's better to have two locked doors, than one.